# How can I make the values display in JTextfield?

Tags: java, database, user-interface, jtextfield

I'm trying to make the user's information from the database  and displays in 3 `JTextField`s when the user open the information on their main `GUI`. I have the sub GUI working but the values are not displaying.

Here's the code for the sub menu.

```
protected void Info() {

    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setBounds(100, 100, 585, 387);
    contentPane = new JPanel();
    contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
    setContentPane(contentPane);
    contentPane.setLayout(null);

    JLabel lblNewLabel = new JLabel("Name");
    lblNewLabel.setFont(new Font("Times New Roman", Font.BOLD, 14));
    lblNewLabel.setBounds(97, 11, 46, 14);
    contentPane.add(lblNewLabel);

    textField = new JTextField();
    textField.setBounds(20, 30, 199, 20);
    contentPane.add(textField);
    textField.setColumns(10);

    textField_3 = new JTextField();
    textField_3.setBounds(242, 30, 86, 20);
    contentPane.add(textField_3);
    textField_3.setColumns(10);

    textField_2 = new JTextField();
    textField_2.setBounds(338, 30, 86, 20);
    contentPane.add(textField_2);
    textField_2.setColumns(10);

    JLabel lblNewLabel_1 = new JLabel("Grade Level");
    lblNewLabel_1.setFont(new Font("Times New Roman", Font.BOLD, 14));
    lblNewLabel_1.setBounds(242, 11, 76, 14);
    contentPane.add(lblNewLabel_1);

    JLabel lblNewLabel_2 = new JLabel("Reading Level");
    lblNewLabel_2.setFont(new Font("Times New Roman", Font.BOLD, 14));
    lblNewLabel_2.setBounds(338, 11, 93, 14);
    contentPane.add(lblNewLabel_2);

    try{
        String query= ("select FirstName,GradeLevel,ReadingLevel from Student where FirstName=? AND GradeLevel=? AND ReadingLevel=?");

        PreparedStatement statement=connection.prepareStatement(query);
        Connection connection=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:C:\\Users\\Butch\\Desktop\\Database\\Books.sqlite");
        statement.setString(1,textField.getText());
        statement.setString(2,textField_3.getText());
        statement.setString(3,textField_2.getText());

        ResultSet resultset=statement.executeQuery();
        if(resultset.next())
        {
            String FN=resultset.getString("FirstName");
            textField.setText(FN);
            String GL=resultset.getString("GradeLevel");
            textField_3.setText(GL);
            String RL=resultset.getString("ReadingLevel");
            textField_2.setText(RL);        
        }       
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
    }
}
```

Is there a part of code that I'm missing needed to run it correctly?

Comment: are you sure you have your column name specified correctly? What does your db look like? can you put a screenshot. Try printing the values before setting it in text field.

Comment: You have to set Connection before the PreparedStatement, I recommend to you to do Class.forName() and then Connection at the same block of GUI code, but if you show more code, it could be helpful to give the best resolution

Comment: try print the results that return from db. Maybe you are just setting empty string for them. I mean, you just need to control whether results are empty or textfields can't display results .

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, it'll be a while before I get back to it.